# ivars allowed in Cocoa Touch-based anonymous category but not in "regular" Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-2.0

I noticed two things when switching between iOS and regular OS X development:

```
//SomeClass.h
@interface SomeClass: SomeUIClass

    @property (retain)SomeProperty* someProperty;

@end

//SomeClass.m
@interface SomeClass ()
{
    SomePrivateVar* somePrivateVar;
}
@end

@implementation SomeClass

@synthesize someProperty;
@end
```

The above will compile just fine under iOS. That is:

1. I can synthesize the property without declaring an ivar explicitly
   in the public @interface
2. I can further declare other private ivars in the .m file under the
   anonymous category (class extension).

However, if compiling for OS X and subclassing some NS-based class as opposed to a UI-based one (say, NSView instead of UIView), both the above things result in compiler errors.

I guess I thought Objective-C 2. allowed for the above in general, but they are only "shortcuts" in iOS? or what's the deal with them being allowed in iOS but not in OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are features of the ["modern runtime"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html) which can only be used for 64 bit apps on Mac OS X. You're probably building a universal binary that also includes a 32 bit version.

Comment: Oh.... aha. Yep, actually I'm building universal 32/64 and as a matter of fact, have to end up compiling in 32 anyway cause for some reason auval (the audio unit validation tool -- I'm building an audio unit plugin) doesn't even see the built component if it's built under 64-bit.